# How can I reduce the itchy portion of growing a beard?

Tags: comfort, hair

So nearing my thirties I'm finally reaching the point in my life where I have enough facial hear to grow a beard and it actually grows fast enough that I wouldn't be waiting several years to accomplish this. I want to grow a beard.

That said, after 2-3 days of not shaving my face and neck are on fire due to several little spears poking me whenever I move. I've tried using hair conditioner along with various oils and products to soften the hairs during this phase, but nothing seems to work; the hairs just aren't long enough at this point to bend on their own.

Comment: You have enough facial hair to grow a *bear*...?

Comment: @lefty it doesn't really thrill my wife, but we all have our crosses to bear. 

Answer (score 3):

I found that when I cut my beard with **hair clippers**, it didn't itch while growing. It was only when I started using a blade razor that I experienced the itch. It might have something to do that a clipper might split the ends of the hair making it softer.

[image: Hair clipplers]

Comment: You might need this clippers for grooming anyways, so probably worth the investment.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the itch never completely goes away even after 30 years of growing one. From time to time the itch returns and then goes away even with the most liberal trimming regime.

Answer (score -1):

Try rubbing coconut oil into the beard/skin every night before bed.  Should help stop the itch.